# Laravel - How Do You Check If Current E-Mail Configuration is Valid Without Sending an E-Mail?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mail

I've written a custom provider that overwrites the e-mail configuration settings in `mail.php` with values populated from a database.  I have a feature in my app that lets users tests the e-mail configuration entered into the system.

I can test whether current credentials are valid by calling `Mail::send()`.  If the configuration isn't valid, the `send()` method will return a reason on why sending the e-mail failed.

Is there anyway for me to check configuration without actually sending an e-mail?

Comment: You can use mailtrap.io service

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Mail::fake();`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mocking#mail-fakes) that doesn't send the email.

Answer (score 0):

In you `/config/mail.php` set `email driver` from `smtp` to `log`. I usually do it in `.env`

```
MAIL_DRIVER=log
```

Then send the mail as usual. You'll get a log with your email in it in `/storage/logs/laravel.log` This would be the easiest method. Further you can use services like [mailtrap.io](https://mailtrap.io/) or [mailthief](https://github.com/tightenco/mailthief)